# In what object does Node.js store variables?

Tags: javascript, node.js

in my server.js:

If I type:

```
var yo = 123;
console.log(global.yo); // undefined
console.log(this.yo); // undefined
```

in the browser this would be window.yo, so is there some object in Node where this variable is stored?

Comment: The javascript language specifies it as "the global object". Traditionally browsers call the global object "window" but the language doesn't require that. It only requires that the global object exist. The language also doesn't require that the global object be accessible to programmers. And newer versions of the language allows you to prevent `this` from referring to the global object when you turn on strict mode.

Answer (score 3):

JavaScript, regardless whether on the browser or on the server, does not store local declared variables on any object, they just exist in the *scope* (and cannot be accessed as properties on anything).

The only exception are global variables, which are accessible as properties of the *global object* (a language term). In browsers, that object is exposed as [`window`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.window), in Node it is exposed as [`global`](http://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_global). It also is the value of the `this` binding in global code.

As stated in the other answers, a file executed with node is not global code, but lives in a module scope, so you usually won't observe this behaviour for any declared variables. It works in the REPL, though:

```
$ node
> var yo = 123;
> global.yo
123
^C
$ echo "var yo = 123; console.log(global.yo)" > test.js
$ node test.js
undefined
$ echo "yo = 123; console.log(global.yo)" > test.js
$ node test.js
123
```

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: no.

Slightly longer answer:

The Node.js documentation [says](http://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_global):

> In browsers, the top-level scope is the global scope. That means that in browsers if you're in the global scope `var something` will define a global variable. In Node this is different. The top-level scope is not the global scope; `var something` inside a Node module will be local to that module.

An important point to remember is that in Node.js, *everything* is a module. This includes entry files (i.e. files you run as `node blah.js`). So every variable being local to its module, they're not accessible on `global` like they would be on `window` in the browser:

```
var yo = 123;
console.log(window.yo); //⇒ 123
```

But in Node:

```
var yo = 123;
console.log(global.yo); //⇒ undefined
console.log(module.yo); //⇒ undefined
```

I can't find any documentation that points this behaviour out, though.

Comment: in a browser, var x = 2 in the global scope does set window.x to 2. the same doesn't happen with node apparently. short answer is of course correct tho

Comment: oddly enough, if you run node from the cmd line and manually define y using var y = 123, it WILL set GLOBAL.y, which is what i based my answer off of.

Comment: Yeah, the Node REPL does things a bit weirdly.

Comment: That's because modules run in their own sandbox

Answer (score 1):

When you declare a variable in javascript with the 'var' keyword it will define the variable in the local scope.

Specifically for browser declering a variable in the global scope will set it to window.

In node declerin a variable with var will always be local. We will never be without a scope. We'll always have the module level.

So no, the variable is not assigned to any object.