# global variable assignment in node from script vs command line

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have the following script:

```
/* script.js */
var bar = "bar1";

function foo() {
    console.log('this.bar: ' + this.bar);
    console.log('global.bar: ' + global.bar);
}
foo();
```

Running `node script.js` returns:

```
this.bar: undefined
global.bar: undefined
```

However, from inside the node command line environment, reproducing the same script returns:

```
this.bar: bar1
global.bar: bar1
```

Further, if I change my variable declaration from `var bar = "bar1";` to `global.bar = "bar1";` both methods of running the above code return:

```
this.bar: bar1
global.bar: bar1
```

What's the difference?  Is global variable assignment somehow different when running a script vs reproducing a script in the same environment?

Comment: Running a script that way is basically running a module, and a module is just basically your code spliced into a function before being `eval`'d and invoked, so the `var` is a local variable in that function. The REPL runs in the global execution context.

Comment: possible duplicate of [In what object does Node.js store variables?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25122846/1048572)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply because every node module is wrapped in an IIFE of sorts, so by default you are not in the global scope.

We can see it happening in `src/node.js`, in the [NativeModule](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/src/node.js#L742) function.

```
NativeModule.require = function(id) {
    // ...
    var nativeModule = new NativeModule(id);

    nativeModule.cache();
    nativeModule.compile();

    return nativeModule.exports;
};
```

Following the trail, we look into `compile`:

```
NativeModule.prototype.compile = function() {
    var source = NativeModule.getSource(this.id);
    source = NativeModule.wrap(source);

    var fn = runInThisContext(source, { filename: this.filename });
    fn(this.exports, NativeModule.require, this, this.filename);

    this.loaded = true;
};
```

`wrap` looks relevant, let's see what it does:

```
NativeModule.wrap = function(script) {
    return NativeModule.wrapper[0] + script + NativeModule.wrapper[1];
};

NativeModule.wrapper = [
    '(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { ',
    '\n});'
];
```

As suspected, it wraps your module's code in an IIFE, meaning you do not run in the global scope.

On the other hand, the REPL [by default](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/src/node.js#L134) runs in the global scope. Following the REPL code is meh, but it basically boils down to [this line](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/lib/repl.js#L132):

```
if (self.useGlobal) {
    result = script.runInThisContext({ displayErrors: false });
} else {
    result = script.runInContext(context, { displayErrors: false });
}
```

Which looks darn relevant to me.

Answer (score 3):

http://nodejs.org/api/globals.html

> var something inside a Node module will be local to that module.

I think that when you run something from file, it is interpreted as module for node. And if you execute in command shell, variable on top of scope become global.