# Function execution context, browser vs. nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

The following function provides two different results, in Node and Browser:

```
(function funfunfun(root, factory) {
    console.log(root === this);
    factory(root);
})(this, function (root) {
    console.log(root === this);
});
```

In node, it will output false twice. In the browser it will output true twice, as I would expect.

So the question is... why?

Comment: interesting, running function in node terminal, results true twice. but running when saved into file show false twice

Comment: Didn't try in node terminal. Now it is even weirder :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a browser, within an unbound function, `this` will point to window object. Thats why you are getting two trues in browser.

Now in nodejs equalent of window is `global`. If you run `this===global` you will get true in repl.

But from file this is not equal to `global`.
[global variable assignment in node from script vs command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25336759/global-variable-assignment-in-node-from-script-vs-command-line)

Comment: Your answer is correct, i dont know why someone downvote it. `Simply because every node module is wrapped in an IIFE of sorts, so by default you are not in the global scope.`

Comment: I have no idea why the down vote as well (certainly not from me :) ).
So what it means is that the function is executed in a different scope than the one it was executed from? Interesting. You learn something new every day.

Answer (score 2):

This might already be known, but just wanted to add to @Subin's answer that if you explicitly bind the functions to the same this, it will return true whether inside script or REPL.

```
(function funfunfun(root, factory) {
    console.log(root === this);
    factory(root);
}).call(this, this, (function (root) {
    console.log(root === this);
}).bind(this, this));
```

Also, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43630118) provides good info on the global object.